# Set empty string for iOS usage description Info.plist keys

Tags: ios, info.plist

Apple recommends to (crashes your app in iOS 10 if you don't) add usage description keys in the `Info.plist` file, like `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` for example. But I didn't find what happens if you let them empty like:

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```

Comment: I too have this doubt. Am too lazy to test this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just found out, they reject your app. Even if you have this key in localization files in order to use a localized string, you still need this in the `Info.plist` file, even though, when developing, **not** having this key present the message in the `Base` localization.